# Does the English word 'six' violate the Sonority Sequencing Principle?

Tags: phonetics, sonority

I'm aware that it's spellt with an X, however phonetically it's [ks]. According to the SSP, plosives should come after fricatives word-finally. Does the spelling with an x stop it from violating the SSP? I know English has special circumstances with s regarding the SSP but I thought that was just with [st] and [sp] word initially.

Comment: also, forgot to add, but does 'slabs' violate it?

Comment: Have you considered that by following your reasoning, almost *every plural in English* violates the principle?

Comment: Note that _ax_ was standard for _ask_ until about 1600 (though both forms existed in Old English, and the earlier root had _-sk-_). Also _wasp_, where both the _-sp-_ and the _-ps-_ form coexisted until recent times; in this case the Proto-Germanic had _-ps-_.

Answer (score 1):

The codas of six and slabs, [ks] and [bz], are in the order "stop-fricative", and in the sequence of features associated with sonority, fricatives are usually said to be more sonorous than stops (it's not the other way around). However, a third option is that stops and fricatives have the same sonority. Admittedly, a sonority plateau is not in conformity with the ideal of rising sonority for onsets and falling sonority for codas, but it's better than a sonority reversal. Notice that English also has [sp, st, sk] onsets but not *[ps,ts,ks]. At the very least, these coda clusters constitute a plateau, so are "outside" the reasoning about sonority and it's relationship to segment ordering.

The coda cluster /bz/ is not actually parallel to /ks/, since /bz/ is always polymorphemic, and the suffixes /-d, -z/ break the general rules regarding possible codas in English.

Comment: -z breaking coda rules is super interesting - do you happen to know of any articles that cover this?

Comment: In the Slavic languages before about 12th century AD every syllable was to comply with the Law of Increasing Sonority aka Law of Open Syllables, so the order of sounds in a syllable could be only like this and it couldn't be violated under no circumstances: fricative - stop (plosive or affricate) - nasal or [v] - liquid - vowel. As you can see, stops were considered more sonorous than fricatives. That's just for reference.

Comment: English does have [ts] in onset position, though only in loan words. It’s frequently in free variation with [t] or [s] (_tsetse fly_, _tsade_, _tsunami_), but not always (_tsimmis_, _Tsonga_, _tsuris_).

Comment: Re polymorphemic /bz/, the Homestar Runner character Bubs comes to mind :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak You could argue that the /z/ at the end of _Bubs_ is a separate morpheme, even that it’s the plural (or possessive) morpheme. It’s a common ending in diminutive names (Margaret > Mags, Barbara > Babs, Gary > Gaz, Philip > Flips/Pips, etc.), and to me it ‘feels’ like a separate morpheme, like _-ie_ or _-ock_ for general diminutives.

Comment: @Janus True, it does have that feel. And it wouldn't help if I argued that it was his full name; plenty of people have diminutive forms on their birth certificate!

Comment: I’m not so sure I’d category the /bz/ in _plebs_ as polymorphemic, though. Sure, there’s _plebeian_ and other words that don’t have the sibilant, so there are hints that it wasn’t part of the root in Latin… but is the _English_ word really polymorphemic? I’d say no.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet plebs absolutely is polymorphemic in British English at least where it's been fully reanalysed as a plural of singular pleb "a commoner (derogatory)" with the usual plural suffix and so is now just as polymorphemic as peas (also originally referring to the collective, but reanalysed as a plural). Cf the reporting around 2012's plebgate

Comment: @Tristan Yes, when reanalysed, it is clearly polymorphemic. But when used as a singular, I wouldn’t say it is. It doesn’t help, of course, that even the non-reanalysed form is mostly used with plural agreement (I would personally use notional agreement, but that doesn’t seem to be the norm). Though rarer, _urbs_ might be a better example: though that too has been reanalysed (yielding the new singular _urb_), in its original form, it is at least generally used with singular agreement.